# Turn a UIView into a UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

How can I turn a UIView (with subviews as UIImageViews) into a UIImage programatically?

Is this a common practice?

Comment: It certainly is not entirely common but sometimes needed. Suppose you want to create some totally awesome animation that shows/hides your view. Suppose that animation needs to divide your view into several segments (e.g folding). For such scenarios, it is inevitable to use a "hardcopy" of your original view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you want a "screenshot" of a particular view?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size); 
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Awesomely simple. Thanks for the code snippet. Good thing to add to a category for UIView so it's always available.

Comment: Edited tiny detail: view.size I think needs to be view.frame.size

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a Swift 4 answer on iOS 10+

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: view.bounds)
let image = renderer.image { rendererContext in
    view.layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
}
```